# How to get this height with MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, media-queries, responsiveness

Edit: I think my descirption wasn't all too clear. I need the heigth between app bar und nav bar as a double so I can size other things with that.

I'm done coding the logic for my app and have just started with implementing the design someone made for me. A lot of the elements in my app are scaled according to the available height. The problem, I'm not quite sure how to get that reliably. So...how do I get the height indicated by the red line in the screenshot (taken from the design):

[image]

**My approach:**

availableHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - appBarHeight - BottomNavHeight - ?

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to figure out the height of the bottom navigation? I have the appBarHeight as I control it manually.
- And what else has to be substracted from the total height? Are there default paddings or anything else?
- What is the effect, if I wrap everything in a SafeSpace widget? How do I account for that? (Nor sure, if I will yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to get the available area for you to use.

In that case, just use `LayoutBuilder` widget. It will give you the area available at the spot where you use it.

For example:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('LayoutBuilder Example')),
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      print(constraints.maxWidth);
      return FlutterLogo();
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey, I think I wasnt super clear about what I need. I need the value as a double to size other elements of my screen (e.g. to give them 20% of the max avaiable height).

Comment: @Joe Yeah, you can do that with `LayoutBuilder`, you can print out "constraints.maxHeight" and it'll give you exactly the height of the white area in your pictures. Although, if you just want 20% of total height, an even simpler way is to use `FractionallySizedBox`, it's like SizedBox but fractional, just pass in 0.2 for 20%.

Comment: @Joe In other words, you really want to get the white area, and the approach *you think you need*, is to get the total area and then minus the top and the bottom. But in Flutter, you can directly get what you want with `LayoutBuilder`.  And if you just want 20% of parent, there are even simpler ways.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I saw my approach in a tutorial a couple of weeks ago. I like this a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

i think u wanna to try get remainder layout between appbar-navbar, it's automatically fully using so nothing difficult

Comment: Hey, I think I wasnt super clear about what I need. I need the value as a double to size other elements of my screen (e.g. to give them 20% of the max avaiable height).